# Subset one dataframe with each row values of another dataframe and sum distance column

Tags: r, dplyr, sum, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes df1 and df2, i want to groupby df1$delivery and create subset of df2 where one column df2$destination is equal df1$facility column and another df2$source column is not equal to same df1$facility and sum the df2$distance column

df1

```
facility delivery vol
ludhiana  abohar 123
delhi     abohar 234
mumbai    abohar 345
delhi     Adampu 739
jaipur    Adampu 21757
lucknow   Adampu 37449
```

df2

```
 source    destination dist
   delhi    ludhiana    10
   mumbai   ludhiana    5
   ludhiana delhi       10
   mumbai   delhi       5
   ludhiana mumbai      5
   delhi    mumbai      5
   delhi    jaipur      5
   jaipur   delhi       5
   delhi    lucknow     10
   lucknow  delhi       10
   jaipur   lucknow     5
   lucknow  jaipur      5
```

output expected

```
facility delivery vol   pan_india_dist
ludhiana  abohar  123   10
delhi     abohar  234   15
mumbai    abohar  345   10
delhi     Adampu  739   15
jaipur    Adampu  21757 10
lucknow   Adampu  37449 15

x <- sapply(data4$facility,function(i)sum((mh_mh$destination[data4$facility %in% i]) & (mh_mh$source[!data4$facility %in% i]))
```

I had tried this formula but it is throwing not meaningful factors error

Comment: can you explain how you get value 10 for first row?

Comment: Can you use `dput` or `reprex` to make a reproducible example? It will make it easier for people to help you with your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: sorry the first row is suppose to be 15, Logic for arriving at value 15 in first row is as below, for each facility name in df1 ,ex: ludhiana, filter df2$destination = ludhiana and df2$source != ludhiana, and add all the values in df2$dist column, groupby df1$delivery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option with `rap` and `tidyverse`

```
library(rap)
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
    rap(x = ~ filter(df2, destination == facility, source != facility)) %>% 
    mutate(x = map2(x, delivery, ~ 
             .x %>% 
               filter(source %in% df1$facility[df1$delivery == .y])  %>% 
               summarise(pan_india_dist = sum(dist)))) %>%
    unnest
#  facility delivery   vol pan_india_dist
#1 ludhiana   abohar   123             15
#2    delhi   abohar   234             15
#3   mumbai   abohar   345             10
#4    delhi   Adampu   739             15
#5   jaipur   Adampu 21757             10
#6  lucknow   Adampu 37449             15
```

Comment: not able to find rap library, I have installed RAP library but the function doesnt belong to that package

Comment: Error in Ops.factor(destination, facility) : 
  level sets of factors are different

Comment: @VasukiRao  I have the dataset columns as 'character' instead of factor for the faciliyt, delivery, destination, source etc

Comment: Quick top up on the same question, what change would be required in the code, if i want to take product of vol * dist before summation. ie. sum(vol X product) which will give be weighted distance

Comment: @VasukiRao  shouldn't the `sum(vol * dist)` works in `summarise`

Comment: Did try the same but apparently the result is coming way off, the actual result for abohar - ludhiana pair for mumbai and delhi is suppose to be sum((234*10)+(345*5)) = 4065, however if i do (dist * vol) i get result way off such as 414360